# Roll up summary using apex code

Tags: apex, roll-up-summary

```java
trigger BankAndCreditcardParentChildTriggerRollUpSummary on Credit_card__c (After insert, After Delete, After Update ) {
    Set<ID> BankIdSet = new Set<ID>();
    
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(Credit_card__c cred : trigger.new){
            BankIdSet.add(cred.Bank__c);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isdelete){
        for(Credit_card__c cred : trigger.old){
            BankIdSet.add(cred.Bank__c);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Credit_card__c cred : trigger.new){
            BankIdSet.add(cred.Bank__c);
        }
    }
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Credit_card__c cred : trigger.old){
            BankIdSet.add(cred.Bank__c);
        }
    }

    List<Bank__c> BankList = [select id, Name, Count_of_Credit_Card__c, Total_Balance__c, (select id, Name, Balance__c from Credit_cards__r) from Bank__c where id IN: BankIdSet ];
    for(Bank__c b :BankList ){
        b.Count_of_Credit_Card__c = b.Credit_cards__r.size();
    }

    Update BankList;
    
    if(trigger.isAfter) {
        if(trigger.isInsert){
            Set<ID> BankIdSet = new Set<ID>();
            List<Bank__c> BankToUpdateList = new List<Bank__c>();
            List<Credit_card__c> ccList = new List<Credit_card__c> ();

            for(Credit_card__c cred : ccList){
                if(cred.Bank__c != NUll){
                    BankIdSet.add(cred.Bank__c);
                }
            }

            for(Bank__c b :[select id, Name, Total_Balance__c,(select id, Name, Balance__c from Credit_cards__r ) from Bank__c where ID IN:BankIdSet ]){
                b.Total_Balance__c = 0;

                for(Credit_card__c cred : b.Credit_cards__r){
                    system.debug('cred' +cred);
                    if(cred.Balance__c != NUll){
                        b.Total_Balance__c = b.Total_Balance__c + cred.Balance__c;
                    }
                }
                BankToUpdateList.add(b);
            }

            update BankToUpdateList;
        }
    }
}
```

I have two tasks

1. calculate no. of credit cards on parent(bank) which is working fine
2. calculate the sum of all balance on credit cards added to respective banks(this is not working).

Can anyone help??

Comment: This looks like very good case to use standard roll-up summary feature. Why aren't you using that?

Answer (score 6):

#### You probably shouldn't try this yourself unless you know what you're doing (or are specifically trying to learn)

If your two objects have a master-detail relationship, then you shouldn't be doing this in code (and using a rollup summary field instead).

If you just have a lookup relationship between the two, then you should strongly consider using the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool (DLRS)](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries#declarative-rollups-for-lookup-field-relationships). It'll create the required code (and the tests) for you.

#### If you still insist on rolling your own

I imagine the primary issue here is that your code to sum the balances is only being run `after insert` for a new Credit Card. If you're simply updating the balance of an existing card, of course the *update* wouldn't execute code that runs on *insert*.

That aside, you can make your code simpler and only use a single query by taking advantage of [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm). You can get the total number of cards under a bank by using `COUNT()`, and the sum of card balances using `SUM()`. The key to doing that is to query on Credit_Card__c and filter on the Bank Ids instead of the Credit Card Ids (otherwise, you'd only get a partial count/sum that only includes the records in the current trigger chunk).

So you'd want a query along the lines of

```
[SELECT 
    Bank__c, COUNT(Id) numCards, SUM(Balance__c) totalBalance 
FROM 
    Credit_Card__c 
WHERE 
    Bank__c IN :bankIdSet 
GROUP BY 
    Bank__c];
```

That'll get you most of the way there, but there is an edge case that many people forget about. How do you handle the scenario where a parent record loses its last child record?

If you don't handle that scenario, your parent record will be stuck with the rollup values from before the dml delete that removed the final child record(s).

The simple solution to that is to use a `Map<Id, ParentSObject>`, iterate over your trigger records, and put an instance of your Parent object into that map *with the rollup fields explicitly set to 0*.

If your parent records still do have child records, the loop over the `List<AggregateResult>` can simply overwrite the value in the map.
If there are no more child records for a given parent, you'll still have data in the map to ensure that the parent rollup fields are zeroed out.